# Not reading text in a right way node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a sales tax problem with node js and I am trying to read text from a file input.txt then calculate the taxes and prices as a final output.
I used the function below to read the file input.txt line by line and it's working

```
      var fs = require('fs'),
  readline = require('readline');
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input : fs.createReadStream('input.txt'),
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
  })
  rl.on('line',function(line){
    console.log(line)
    
  })
```

But the problem is when I tried use the function scanProduct() on that text it didn't work.
This is the whole code

```
    var Cart = require('./src/Cart');


    var cart1 = new Cart();
    var cart2 = new Cart();
    var cart3 = new Cart();

    cart1.scanProduct('1 book at 12.49');
    cart1.scanProduct('1 music CD at 14.99');
    cart1.scanProduct('1 chocolate bar at 0.85');

    cart2.scanProduct('1 imported box of chocolates at 10.00');
    cart2.scanProduct('1 imported bottle of perfume at 47.50');

    // cart3.scanProduct('1 imported bottle of perfume at 27.99');
    // cart3.scanProduct('1 bottle of perfume at 18.99');
    // cart3.scanProduct('1 packet of headache pills at 9.75');
    // cart3.scanProduct('1 box of imported chocolates at 11.25');


    var fs = require('fs'),
    readline = require('readline');
    var rl = readline.createInterface({
      input : fs.createReadStream('input.txt'),
      output: process.stdout,
      terminal: false
    })
    rl.on('line',function(line){
      //console.log(line)
      cart3.scanProduct(line) 
    })

    console.log(cart1.bill());
    console.log("\n");
    console.log(cart2.bill());
    console.log("\n");
    console.log(cart3.bill());
```

scanProduct() and bill() are fuction used to calculate taxes and give the final output and it's working in cart1 and car2 that way. When I tried to get text from the file it didn't work.

Comment: "Doesn't work" how, exactly?  If the `scanProduct()` functionality is failing in some way then the first thing to point out here is that we don't know what that function is or what it does.  This is a good opportunity for you to start debugging your code.  Observe the inputs and results for each individual operation.  Which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the inputs?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Answer (score 0):

It fails because reading of a file is an asynchronous operation and `cart3.bill()`
function is called before `cart3.scanProduct(line)` function.
You should listen to an 'end' event of a readable stream then call the `cart3.bill()` function.
Like this:

```
rl.on('end',function(){
  console.log(cart3.bill()); 
})
```